# Cannot resolve too many methods

Tags: java, android

This is for my school project and yup I'm still new at android programming. I have no idea about why these error messages keep showing up.

> The error messages is:

- a. cannot resolve method 'onCreate(savedInstanceState)' on the part after 'Super'

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.workouttimer);
  ```
- b. cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

  ```
  mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

  mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
  mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
  ```
- c. cannot resolve method 'onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)'

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
  outState.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
  outState.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
  }
  ```
- d. cannot resolve method 'onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)'

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  mTimeLeftInMillis = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisLeft");
  mTimerRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("timerRunning");
  updateCountDownText();
  updateButtons();
  ```

This is my timer.java (actually this is my second mainactivity java because my application is multi-activity)

```
package com.example.lenovo.pomodorotest;


import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class timer {
private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;

private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
private Button mButtonStartPause;
private Button mButtonReset;

private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

private boolean mTimerRunning;

private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
private long mEndTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.workouttimer);

    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

    mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
    mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

    mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTimerRunning) {
                pauseTimer();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    });

    mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetTimer();
        }
    });

    updateCountDownText();
}



private void setContentView(int workouttimer) {
}

private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateButtons();
        }
    }.start();

    mTimerRunning = true;
    updateButtons();
}

private void pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    updateButtons();
}

private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();
    updateButtons();
}

private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}

private void updateButtons() {
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
    } else {
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    outState.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    outState.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mTimeLeftInMillis = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisLeft");
    mTimerRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("timerRunning");
    updateCountDownText();
    updateButtons();

    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("endTime");
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        startTimer();
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

This is my workouttimer.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start_pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Studying!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start_letsgetrest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_start_pause"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Lets Get Rest!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_start_pause"
    android:text="reset"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools":visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_start_pause" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `public class timer extends AppCompatActivity {`

Comment: extend your class to appcompactactivity

Comment: I'm no Android expert but your problem is that you are declaring in your "timer" class (It shoul be Timer by Java conventions) that you are overriding some methods. Those methods should be in a superclass and you have defined no parent for "timer". (Object is used by default in java and it has not such methods)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiyaThank you so much! ({}) Case closed! :)))

Comment: Case closed? I don't think so. You have to study a bit more to fully understand what you are coding, not just copy what you found in internet. Good luck!

Comment: @RubioRic well said.

Comment: @RubioRic well, thats why I asked because in real life, my friends dont understand (we are not studying that deep and just doing what books told us too even this basic we dont know nothing about) and my teacher is out of reach :)) Thanks for the advice btw :)

Comment: Well, if you are programming in java, you should learn Object Oriented Programming basics (in java) before programming phone apps. There are a lot of tutorials and books about the subject out there. :-)

Comment: And in relation with your class being named "timer" ... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your timer.java file to this and then rebuild

```
public class timer extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: welcome :) Do upvote and mark the answer as correct :')

Answer (score 2):

All of the methods that you are overriding is from the class AppCompatActivity or Activity.Hence, to use these methods in your class, you will have to extend the classes AppCompatActivity or Activity like -

```
public class timer extends AppCompatActivity{
//Your code
}
```

Note - Please, while creating classes, start it with a capital letter as per convention.